# Anchor links turn to p nbsp p

Tags: posts

whenever i try to add anchor links (like a name=''section1''a) and then link the texts within the same post (like #section1), anchor links turn to p nbsp p after i save the changes. So it doesn't work. Is there something i do wrong? 
PS: Can't type the codes correctly because they disappear

Comment: You can add code by hitting the {} code button, it would be helpful so we can see what you are actually attempting

Comment: I didn't understand the problem but it got solved itself. Thank you